# (Java GUI) JPanel not showing up returning through method after removeAll() method

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Below, I'm creating a JFrame class (Just the important parts are posted below in the class). When creating a UserInterface object everything works expect when activating the eventListener. This section of code :

```
getContentPane().removeAll();
getContentPane().add(gameScreen());
getContentPane().validate();
getContentPane().repaint();
```

Doesnt seem to work as wanted. The removeAll() method functions, but adding the gameScreen method (which returns panel) to JFrame doesn't do anything. Any idea why?

```
public class UserInterface extends JFrame{

public UserInterface(){
    super("idk");
    setName("idk");
    setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    add(startScreen());
    setVisible(true);
}//UserInterface

private class beginButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        getContentPane().removeAll();
        getContentPane().add(gameScreen());
        getContentPane().validate();
        getContentPane().repaint();
    }
}//beginButtonListener

public JPanel gameScreen(){

    JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
    gamePanel.setName("gamePanel");
    gamePanel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel fadeShade = new JLabel();
    fadeShade.setName("fadeShade");
    fadeShade.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    fadeShade.setBounds(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    gamePanel.add(fadeShade);
    return gamePanel;
}//gameScreen
}//UserInterface
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, your gamePanel likely does get added, but you'll never see it. You add a JLabel to it without any text on the label, and you set the label's background color without making the label opaque. You also use null layouts, a very dangerous thing to do.

If this were my code, I'd

- Use a CardLayout to swap components
- Avoid `null` layouts like the plague and instead let the layout managers do the heavy layout lifting for me.
- Make sure to set the text of any JLabel that needs to display text. Setting the JLabel's name property likely wouldn't help me much.

Comment: Wow this whole time it was a careless mistake. Thanks for pointing that out! I'll definitely make those changes.